# Store Palladium Chloride in Solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, stoichiometry, transition-metals, stability

I have one gram of palladium chloride ($\ce{PdCl2}$) and I want to use very small quantities of it, in milligrams somewhere. It is not possible for me to get my hands on a scale that can measure that low quantity. When I shall be dissolving it in HCl solution during use.
So what if I prepare its solution in HCl and then use that solution by measuring its volume in a syringe and calculating how much $\ce{PdCl2}$ there is in the solution? I have seen 5 wt% $\ce{PdCl2}$ in 10 wt% HCl solution available on the internet. So I take 54 mL of 37 % HCl and dilute it to 200 mL to get 10 % HCl. Then add 1 g of $\ce{PdCl2}$ to it. Then I can say that for every mL of the solution, I have 5mg of $\ce{PdCl2}$.
How much shelf life will this solution have? What kind of container should I use to store it? Or is there a better way to store it in the solution and measure small quantities of it?

Answer (score 0):

I remember during undergrad storing Pd catalysts in a brown glass jar in the fridge. If making up 0.25g, you could use a brown 50 ml dropper bottle or something similar. As for shelf life, I would suggest making up 0.25 g, dating the jar and checking to see if the reaction stops working at any point. To measure the the amount, use a syringe and needle.

Comment: Was it Palladium Chloride in HCl that you stored in the brown glass jar?

Comment: No, Pd2dba3 came in a brown glass jar.